# Google asking about Google Play requires policy but I have the valid Permissions in Manifest file?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, permissions, google-play-services, android-manifest

I developed an android game in Unity, and I only add the two permission in manifest(Internet permission and Internet Access). but Google play warning us about privacy policy that you had added other permission in manifest.xml (e.g. camera, microphone, accounts, contacts, or phone)

**Google play service warning message:**

> Policy issue: Google Play requires developers to provide a valid privacy policy when the app requests or handles sensitive user or device information. Your app requests sensitive permissions (e.g. camera, microphone, accounts, contacts, or phone) or user data, but does not include a valid privacy policy.
>
> Action required: Include a link to a valid privacy policy on your app's Store Listing page and within your app. You can find more information in our help center.

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
        </activity>

        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />

        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
             android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Please Solve my problem why that error is coming, And what is the solution of it??**

Comment: you need to give a link in your app and also on play console to your app privacy policy. search google for creating privacy policy.

Comment: We have valid permission in but google asking about other permissions, we have not added that permission in manifest, would you like to tell us how we can identify that where that permission is added my code??

Comment: They are not in your manifest. It may be a mistake from google side, but to be caution you need to submit privacy policy and also contact google for this problem. Otherwise It may have harmful effect on your account

Comment: Thank you for your helpful suggesstion

Comment: Also I've not work with unity. It may be possible that this library also has manifest file and after compiling your apk your manifest got merged with unity manifest.hence all these permissions are there

Answer (score 1):

I think the permission in your manifest file is not enough. Since your app seems to be collecting private data (Email add, Device ID
First and last name, Billing or shipping information, etc), you need a link to a privacy policy which states how your are gathering and using the private data.

**Why the need?**

[Google Play for Families FAQ](https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/families/faq.html) states that

> Do I need to provide an up-to-date privacy policy and where do I do
>   that?
>
> Yes, you need to provide a link to a persistent privacy policy on your
>   app’s store listing and confirm your compliance with local privacy
>   statutes in the Developer Console. To add or review your privacy
>   policy, choose your app in the Developer Console and then scroll to
>   the bottom of the Store Listing section.

If you also read from [Privacy Policy for mobile apps](https://termsfeed.com/blog/privacy-policy-mobile-apps/) you will know that big companies apps like Dropbox, Slack, Flurry,etc are required to have their Privacy Policy links.

[Where to Place](http://www.iubenda.com/blog/privacy-policy-for-ios-apps/)?

1. Embed it into your app or link to it from the app;
2. Possibly link to it from the app store;
3. Possibly link to it from your website;

**Where to Get?**

This I haven't tried. There are several names out there like [iubenda](http://www.iubenda.com/blog/privacy-policy-for-android-app/) and [privacypolicies](https://privacypolicies.com/). Hope you find your PP provider.